# Pytest flask view with API call - connection refused

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, pytest

My pytest setup for testing flask does not work when a flask view contains a call to the API (within the same flask app). The Flask app has two blueprints - a front end (intake) and a back end (api).

The view "intake.uploads" sends a request to "api.lists" to get the full list of rows from the database. This works fine when I run the app, in development or production environments, but when pytest tries to run this, we get a connection refused error on the API call.

The pytests work when calling a view that doesn't involve an API call, or when testing the API calls directly.

intake.uploads:

```
@bp.route('/uploads')
def uploads():
    """Page for viewing previously initiated list uploads."""
    api_url, headers = get_api_config()
    lists = requests.get(url_for('api.lists', _external=True),
                         headers=headers)
    lists = lists.json()['lists']
    return render_template('intake/uploads.html', title='Voter Lists',
                           lists=lists)
```

api.lists:

```
class ListAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        """Returns all lists."""
        try:
            alllists = Voterlist.query.all()
            lists = []
            for l in alllists:
                l = l.__dict__
                l.pop('_sa_instance_state', None)
                lists.append(l)
            return jsonify({'lists': lists})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            abort(400, str(e))

api = Api(bp)
api.add_resource(ListAPI, '/api/v1.0/lists', endpoint='lists')
```

conftest.py:

```
class TestConfig(Config):
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///test.db'
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
    BCRYPT_LOG_ROUNDS = 4

def fill_database():
    s0 = Source(title='Catalist')
    s1 = Source(title='L2')
    sources = [s0, s1]
    l0 = Voterlist(description='Test List 0')
    l1 = Voterlist(description='Test List 1')
    lists = [l0, l1]
    return lists, sources

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def test_client():
    flask_app = create_app(TestConfig)
    with flask_app.test_client() as client:
        app_context = flask_app.test_request_context()
        app_context.push()
        db.create_all()
        lists, sources = fill_database()
        for s in sources:
            db.session.add(s)
            db.session.commit()
        for l in lists:
            db.session.add(l)
            db.session.commit()
            sleep(1)
        yield client
        db.drop_all()
    app_context.pop()
```

test_intake.py:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('test_client')
class TestUploads():
    def test_page_loads(self, test_client):
        '''
        Uploads page loads.
        '''
        response = test_client.get(url_for('intake.uploads'))
        assert b'Voter Lists' in response.data
```

SO won't let me post the full pytest output (too long), so here's the error at the bottom:

```
E           requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1.0/lists (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7b9b6150d860>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

/home/alazar66/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:516: ConnectionError
```

Answer (score 0):

After much searching around, it seems that the way I was using the API within the same flask app was a bit unconventional. I changed it so that API calls within the app call the method directly rather than making an http request.

intake.uploads:

```
@bp.route('/uploads')
def uploads():
    """Page for viewing previously initiated list uploads."""
    api_url, headers = get_api_config()
    response = routes.ListAPI.get(routes.ListAPI)
    lists = response.json['lists']
    return render_template('intake/uploads.html', title='Voter Lists',
                           lists=lists)
```

This is working now.